# ExecuteNonQuery doesn't update SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using these lines to connect to sql server

```
SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(testing, conn);
scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

if the value of `testing` is simple :

```
string testing = "Insert INTO People (ID, Name) values (123,'Lara')";
```

it works perfectly.
But if I used something like :

```
String testing = "Insert INTO People (ID, Name) values (123,'Lara')" +
                 " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Name = 'Lara'";
```

The SQL server is not updated and the code goes to catch statement, also if I used the `if exist` it doesn't work as well. 
  Here is my code for more clarification :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName;" +
    "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
    "Integrated Security=True;");

try
{
    conn.Open();
    string testing= "Insert INTO People (ID, Name) values (123,'Lara')";
    SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(testing, conn);
    scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved! ");
}    
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Halted! ");
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: `code goes to catch statement` What is the error ?

Comment: It s Mysql syntax remove Sql-Server tag

Comment: @JaydipJ - but since the OP is using the SQL Server client objects (`SqlCommand` et al), it seems likely they are working with SQL Server.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but is there any syntax like this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ` in Sql Server, Correct me if m i wrong

Comment: @JaydipJ - no, there isn't. But which is more likely - that the OP is using MySql, has somehow managed to get the SQL Server specific client objects to connect to it, and they're generating a runtime error, or that the OP is using SQL Server and has copied and pasted some mysql specific code into their project?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this may be case of copy paste thats why I am doubt full for for tag, any way thank Damien

Answer (score 0):

There's no `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` equivalent, but `MERGE` and `WHEN MATCHED` might work for you

[Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.100).aspx)